# Long time open database connection and SQL join query memory

Tags: mysql, oracle, jdbc

I'm currently working on a java application which performs following in a background thread.

1. opens database connection
2. Select some rows (100000+ rows)
3. perform a long running task for each row by calling ResultSet.next() with some buffer size defined by resultSet.setFetchSize()
4. finally after everything's done closes the connection

If the query does some sorting or joining it will create a temp table and will have some additional memory usage. My question is if my database connection is being opened for long time (let's say few hours) and fetch batch by batch slowly, will it cause performance trouble's in database due to memory usage? (If the database is concurrently used by other threads also.) Or databases are designed to handle these things effectively?

(In the context of both MySQL and Oracle)

Answer (score 1):

From an Oracle perspective, opening a cursor and fetching from it periodically doesn't have that much of an impact if it's left open... unless the underlying data that the cursor is querying against changes since the query was first started.

If so, the Oracle database now has to do additional work to find the data as it was at the start of the query (since read-consistency!), so now it needs to query the data blocks (either on disk or from the buffer cache) and, in the event the data has changed, the undo tablespace.

If the undo tablespace is not sized appropriately and enough data has changed, you may find that your cursor fetches fail with an "ORA-01555: snapshot too old" exception.

In terms of memory usage, a cursor doesn't open a result set and store it somewhere for you; it's simply a set of instructions to the database on how to get the next row that gets executed when you do a fetch. What gets stored in memory is that set of instructions, which is relatively small when compared to the amount of data it can return!

Answer (score 1):

this mechanism seems not good.

although both mysql(innodb engine) and oracle provides consistent read for select,

do such a long select may leads to performance downgrade due to build cr block and other work,

even ora-01555 in oracle.

i think you should query/export all data first,

then process the actual business one by one.

at last, query all data first will not reduce the memory usage,

but reduce the continus time for memory and temp sort segment/file usage.

or you shoud consider separete the whole work to small pieces,

this is better.